# Grafana with MongoDB as data source

Tags: mongodb, grafana

Does grafana support MongoDB as a data source (given that all the MongoDB documents are structured and have a time field)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for mongoDB at the moment.

Comment: Hi Carl, I see that you are a Grafana developer. Are there any plans to support it in the future? I think the only requirement is that each document should have a timestamp. Is there any workaround at the moment (e.g. any unofficial plugin)?

Comment: We have no plans for adding support for mongodb in core Grafana. We are currently working on support for plugins in the backend which would enable someone to write a plugin for it. But we just started so its far from ready :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone has written a plugin for that: [mongodb-grafana](https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana)